# Размытое пятно CSS

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка

Здравствуйте, как сделать эффект такого размытого пятна как внизу на скриншоте? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Свойство box-shadow

Answer (score 1):

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #0B0B0B;
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #00E676;
  position: relative;
}

h1:before,
h1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: #00E676;
}

h1:after {
  top: 60px;
  height: 16px;
  opacity: .1;
  filter: blur(8px);
}
```

```html
<h1>Ausweis</h1>
```